# Python: PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, path

This should be a very pedestrian question, but how do I go about making it so that everytime I write a new python library, or download one from Github, I can just do:

`$ import my_module`

or

`$ import github_module`

without any fuss?

Is there a recommended directory in which to save all my custom or downloaded modules?  Just in case: I installed Python3.6 using `brew install`, because some Youtube video told me that this is the neatest way to do it.

Attempted solutions:

- Appending `/path/to/my_module` to `sys.path` every time. Sort of
  works, but not neat.
- Tinkering with the `./profile`, or `./bash_profile`. However, after I saved the session and tried to reopen my terminal again, bash wouldn't recognise any of my commands like `jupyter notebook`. I did an emergency undo to revert the `./profile` file to its original state. Given my lack of knowledge of the Mac OS, I'm wary of messing with these files unless I really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using a python package manager like [miniconda](https://conda.io/docs/get-started.html);
then install packages with

```
conda install blahblah
```

it saves lot of time and pain!

and git sources can be installed using pip, (which also comes with miniconda) like

```
pip install -e git://git.myproject.org/MyProject.git@master#egg=MyProject
```

look [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git)